# Hg merge -> revert -> merge

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, revert

I've stuck with a small Mercurial problem: I merged a branch A into a branch B and everything succeeded, but after that one of my teammates reverted the branch B back to pre-merge status.
Now I need to merge branch A once again into branch B, but I get the following error:

```
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can backout revision that reverted your branch B. This will create new changeset with inverted modifications that was applied in "revert" changeset.